# Regarding another definition of skewness of an RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be an RV with $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu$, $m$ a population median of $X$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2$. We define the skewness $S$ of $X$ by
> $$S:= \frac{\mu - m}{\sigma}.$$
> REMARK: A population median is defined as follows: Let $X$ be a RV. Then $m$ is a population median of $X$ if $P[X \ge m] \ge 1/2$ and $P[X \le m] \le 1/2$ holds. This is equivalent to $m$ is a minimiser of $g(v):=\mathbb{E}(\vert X - v \vert)$.
>
> I need to show that:
>
> 1. $S \in [-1,1]$
> 2. Are the bounds neat? When are they reached?

I suppose that the fact that $\sigma = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2}$, could be helpful here, but I do not see how to proceed here. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$E[|X-m|] \le E[|X-\mu|] \le \sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]} = \sigma$$
The first inequality is due to the characterization of the median as a minimizer of $g(v)=E[|X-v|]$; the second inequality is Jensen's inequality.

To finish the first question, find a connection between the left-hand side of the above with $|\mu-m|$.

---

For the second inequality, use the intuition that $S$ represents skew. Make a sequence of simple distributions that you think has more and more skew and see how $S$ behaves.

> A very weird example is just the $\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ distribution. Any number in $[0,1]$ serves as a median, so choosing $m=0$ gives $S=1$. (Of course, choosing $m=1/2$ gives $S=0$.)

> For something less odd, you can approximate this with $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ as follows. For $p < 1/2$, the median must be $m=0$. We have $\mu=p$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$ so $S = \sqrt{p / (1-p)}$. As $p \uparrow 1/2$ we have $S \to 1$.